# Android Studio crashes Mac OS due to symbolic link

Tags: android-studio, osx-elcapitan

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.1 on Mac OSX El Captain. 
Here are my Android Studio version details:

> Android Studio 2.2.1 Build #AI-145.3330264, built on October 6, 2016 
>   JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b05 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
>   JetBrains s.r.o

Here are my Mac details:

> Model Name:   MacBook Pro
>   Model Identifier: MacBookPro12,1
>   Processor Name:   Intel Core i5
>   Processor Speed:  2,7 GHz
>   Number of Processors: 1
>   Total Number of Cores:    2
>   L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 3 MB   Memory:  8 GB
>   Boot ROM Version: MBP121.0167.B17
>   SMC Version (system): 2.28f7

I'm using some cpp files in my android projects and it's on my module path. My module in ˜metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/mymodule and cpp files in ˜metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/cppmodule.

I created symbolic link from ˜metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/mymodule/src/main/jni/c to ˜metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/cppmodule .

When I try to open my cpp files through the Project Panel in the path of ˜metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/mymodule/src/main/jni/c it opens and there is no exception. But when I try to open cpp file through the Project Panel in the path of ˜metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/cppmodule Android Studio crashes and gives this error:

```
Crashed Thread:        27  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0 2.2#AI-145.3330264 Studio, eap:false, os
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) 
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000f2a93ca3 
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Here is the [paste](http://pastebin.com/W0UPwxRW) for detailed  Android Studio quit unexpectedly error.

I think this is symbolic link error but might be something else.

**EDIT 1:**
Also I saw this error for my all cpp files.

Failed to get the compiler information for file

> Users/metehantoksoy/Repositories/MyProject/mymodule/src/main/jni/c/initialize.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Android Studio 2.2.3 just installed on a new mac book air. On the bottom line of the frame of the Android Studio on main page is the familiar icon of a little green guy. This launched into a pat of the screen and then allowed me to detach it to run normally. All joy and light!